# How to convert pixel relative focal lengths to mm.

Tags: computer-vision

Ive been playing around with the Intel Realsense R200 Camera.
I am able to exact focal length in x and y i.e. fx and fy,
but only "up to scale relative to pixel width and height, respectively"

At the moment I dont see any way of querying the pixel dimensions in mm from the API nor can I find them in the tech specs.

So my question is: How can I get the fx and fy in mm? 
One way I can think of is to take a picture of my checkerboard pattern and count the number of pixels and divide by the size in mm.

Is there a better/more elegant way? It seems kind of..imprecise.

Best,
Marc

Comment: I have trouble seeing this as a computer *science* question. Community votes, please!

Comment: Well its a question about an algorithm which has to compute something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one focal length, $F$. It is the distance between the focal point and the image plane.

The numbers you have, are actually not lengths. They are calculated by $f_x=F\cdot s_x $ and $f_y=F\cdot s_y $  where $s_x$ and $s_y$  are the size of your image in pixels. To get the focal length in mm as you want, simply divide $f_x$ with the width (in pixels) of your image.

Comment: oh really. so just one more question:  I assumed i could transform fx and fy to mm to put into my instrinsic matrix. Extrapolating from your answer this is then not correct. The fx fy values are always in this "relative" space, yes?

Comment: Yes. For more reading check out this: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html